# The word said by a student to denote the end of countdown in a PE class

Tags: word-choice, speech

‎What does the last student in the line say( in a PE class at school) when the class has lined up and counted off?

At the beginning of a PE class, the teacher always asks students to line up in one row. Then he wants to know exactly how many students there are. So he tells the students to count off. So the countdown begins (1st, 2nd, 3nd,...26th) and continues untill it reaches the last student in the line. Then he or she tells her number in the line( for example, 26) and must say:"26th", which is supposed to inevitably be followed by other phrase indicating that that student is the last in the line, so the count down has ended. Declaring this, the student usually leaves the line by making one step forward and reports to the teacher that all the students have counted off.

The wording of such an answer doesn't change from class to class at all, so it's more of a cliché. In my native language we say "The count is over." And I'm interested to know its English equivalents. Is it "The count is off/ over" or something else? I'm aware of the fact that there might be different variants depending on the version of English, so I would narrow it down to British English usage, since it's the version I'm most interested in.

Comment: It seems the teacher is pretty dim if they have  to be told all are counted. In many cases the last student would not say anything at all. There is no set usage for such a thing so answers will be a matter of opinion. I have therefore voted to close.

Comment: I have never witnessed this sort of count occurring, in PE or indeed in any other class, in a school in the UK - so there may well not be an equivalent. (Also note that this wouldn't be a "countdown", since the count is going up, not down :) )

Comment: @Anton A 'no answer' answer is very legitimate. Not having an existing word/phrase does not make a question off-topic. Please do not vote to close questions that you think don't have an answer. There may well be an answer that you don't know of -or- you claim that there is no such word is a good answer. (I would upvote your answer of 'there doesn't exist such a word'.)

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. I see your point. I did not put "there is no answer" as an answer because it would seem presumptuous of me to assume I had complete knowledge.  Nevertheless, I am confident that whatever answers are given will be opinions based on the authors' experiences rather than on generally accepted usage. But your comment is very reflective and I must consider my outlook more carefully. Thanks again.

Comment: @Anton You may want to consider voting to reopen the duplicate question then.

Comment: @MItch I think it is an interesting point so I have (rarely for me) posed it in meta to seek views. It will be interesting to see what the wise think.

Comment: @Mitch, while I agree with your argument that there being no answer to a question is not a good reason for closing it, that argument is not relevant to **this** question: a conclusive argument for closing **it** is that it is a reposting of a question posted by the same user only a day earlier.

Comment: @jsw29 That (reposting a closed question) is true (and that activity is frowned upon).